# Ejabberd error while xml,append_subtags

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am new in erlang and ejabbered/mongooseIM. I am trying to write a very simple mongoose module that will add an extra child element to the packets before sending. Below is my code:

```
-module(mod_test).

-behavior(gen_mod).


-export([start/2, stop/1]).
-export([add_child/1]).

-include("ejabberd.hrl").

start(Host, Opts) ->
    ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, Host, ?MODULE, add_child, 0),
    ?DEBUG(" MOD_TEST Started",[]),
    ok.

stop(Host) ->
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(filter_packet, Host, ?MODULE, add_child, 0),
    ok.

add_child({From, To, XML} = Packet) ->
    Tag = {"a","b"},
    NewPacket = xml:append_subtags(Packet, [Tag]),
    ?INFO_MSG("  To party: ~p~n",[To]),
    NewPacket.
```

I can compile and start the module successfully. However, I get the below error while running:

```
2015-03-04 12:16:30.506 [error] <0.760.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1:259 
{function_clause,
[{xml,append_subtags,[{{jid,<<"user2">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Damien">>,<<"user2">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Damien">>},{jid,<<"user1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Gajim">>,<<"user1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Gajim">>},{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user1@localhost/Gajim">>},{<<"id">>,<<"ab68a">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"mmmmm">>}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>}]}},
[{"a","b"}]],[{file,"src/xml.erl"},{line,276}]},
{safely,apply,3,[{file,"src/safely.erl"},{line,19}]},
{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,255}]},
{ejabberd_router,do_route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,246}]},
{ejabberd_router,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,78}]},
{ejabberd_c2s,session_established2,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,1098}]},
{p1_fsm_old,handle_msg,10,[{file,"src/p1_fsm_old.erl"},{line,542}]},
{proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: For those tracking this issue, the user asked the question in ejabberd.im forum and there is more discussion there: https://www.ejabberd.im/node/24790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `Packet` (a tuple: `{From, To, XML}`) to `xml:append_subtags/2` while you should pass just `XML`. Your `add_child/1` should look more like:

```
add_child({From, To, XML} = Packet) ->
    Tag = {<<"a">>, <<"b">>},
    NewPacket = {From, To, xml:append_subtags(XML, [Tag])},
    ?INFO_MSG("  To party: ~p~n",[To]),
    NewPacket.
```

I also changed `{"a", "b"}` to `{<<"a">>, <<"b">>}` since binaries are used for string processing everywhere in MongooseIM code base.

Moreover, using priority 0 (the last parameter to `ejabberd_hooks:add/5`) is not advised, since this gives you little flexibility in case you actually wanted to insert some handler before this particular one into the handler chain.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. Now dont see those errors anymore, but I was expecting to see the additional tag {a,b} in my packet from the receiving end. But I dont see them unfortunately. I changed the code a little; replaced Tag = {<<"a">>, <<"b">>}, by Tag = {xmlel,<<"time">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Fake-time">>}]}, I can see the extra element has been added to my packet from log. But, the receiving side doesn't get those elements. Any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure you see the custom element added to the packet in a log line saying "Send XML on stream ..."? If yes, then the client should receive the adjusted packet.

Comment: I added a debug line. ?DEBUG("Packet updated to ~p",[NewPacket]),
From there I can see the NewPacket with the added tag. But didnt see Send XML on stream.

Comment: I didn't mean any custom log statements you might have added. When you change logging level to 5 you'll see log entries generated by `ejabberd_c2s`, the component responsible for client to server connections. One of them looks like this: 2015-03-05 17:51:28.255 [debug] <0.554.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1717 Send XML on stream = ...

Comment: If you think the answer is good enough (since there are no others...) would you consider accepting it?

Comment: yeh u gave me the right answer. My code worked... sorry for the delay mate.. keep it up!!